# How to update a specific string in a listbox?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I've been struggling with a string problem in windows form for a few hours.

I have some textboxes where the user can type in "Adress", "zipcode and "city", together with a few combo-boxes.
The user can then click "Add" and the whole item will then be added to a listbox where you can see the different strings the user wrote.

Now I want the user to being able to change a certain string on a selected item.
Example: The user have added this to the textboxes and then clicking ADD and gets this in the listbox:

**Building    Apartment    longstreet    34     7484     London**

-

If the user then click and select this item, I want to be able to write a new adress in the textbox and then update the whole item. If he wrote shortstreet then the listbox will look like this instead:

**Building    Apartment    shortstreet    34     7484     London.**

-

Do you have some ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use a class to store the related data, override the `ToString` method so it appears nice in the listbox, and then when a user selects an item in the listbox, you have all the data you need to populate the form for editing. But really it's hard to help if you don't show the code you currently have.

Comment: + You can use a `BindingList<class>` as the DataSource of your ListBox (or use a BindingSource as *mediator*) and bind the other controls to it (with `[Control].DataBindings.Add()`). Now, you can add addresses to the BindingList and each time you select an existing address from the ListBox, you can directly edit the current Item just typing in your TextBoxes. You'll see the Item in the ListBox update in real time. -- I'd suggest to use a ListViiew instead of a ListBox, so you have Headers and possibly different ways to present your Items, just changing a property. Give it a shot.

Comment: Btw, your Address composition doesn't follow the *rules* :)